# How can I get guid from permanent URL (media selector)?

Tags: kentico

I am using permanent urls for Kentico's media selection in a custom webpart. What I want is the GUID from the url it shows, so I can get the media's info from the data base (using file media provider).

This is an example of the URL

`~/getmedia/998dd0ab-10d3-4cc1-bfbd-8e7bec48cf8c/sample_doc.doc`

What I need is the `998dd0ab-10d3-4cc1-bfbd-8e7bec48cf8c` number. I tried every helper with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I normally get the GUID is through a regular expression rather than the Kentico API.  Try the following:

```
string pattern = @"[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}";
string input = "~/getmedia/998dd0ab-10d3-4cc1-bfbd-8e7bec48cf8c/sample_doc.doc";

var guid = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

The `guid` variable will be set to `998dd0ab-10d3-4cc1-bfbd-8e7bec48cf8c` which you cna then use o get the info you're after.

Comment: Awesome!!, a last one, do you how to get Media Library Direct Path from permanent url or guid, without unchecking "Use Permanent URL" from settings??, I want to download the file with c#  `HttpResponse` so  and `TransmitFile` but I need the direct path for that

Comment: Try looking at `CMS.MediaLibrary.Web.UI.MediaLibraryFunctions.GetMediaFileDirectUrl()`, once you have the MediaFileInfo you should have what you need to call that.